# How to print a big number in character array-string

Tags: c

The number n^k is entered, I need to output the value in a character array-string

I have no idea how to write the code

Comment: [Find a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/). I don't mean you should stop with the problem you're currently trying to solve, but simply break it down into smaller and simpler sub-problems. Do this break-downs until none could be further broken down. Then you will have a set of (hopefully) very small and very simple problems. Solve them, one by one, in any order. When you start to put the together you will start to solve the larger and more complex problems. And finally you have solved your original problem.

Comment: https://github.com/kokke/tiny-bignum-c <-- feel free to get inspired by my bignum-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement your own `pow` that would work with big numbers.

```
int main()
{
    int n, k;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &k);
    char* s = (char*)malloc(1000000);
    int i, j, len, temp, carry;
    s[0] = '1';
    len = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    {
        carry = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < len; j++)
        {
            temp = (s[j] - '0') * n + carry;
            s[j] = temp % 10 + '0';
            carry = temp / 10;
        }
        while (carry > 0)
        {
            s[len] = carry % 10 + '0';
            carry /= 10;
            len++;
        }
    }
    for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Example of pow that takes `n`, `k` while storing result in `str` and returns how big in `length`:

```
void pow(int n, int k, char* str, int* length)
{
    int i, j, carry, temp;
    str[0] = '1';
    *length = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        carry = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < *length; j++)
        {
            temp = (str[j] - '0') * n + carry;
            str[j] = temp % 10 + '0';
            carry = temp / 10;
        }
        while (carry)
        {
            str[*length] = carry % 10 + '0';
            carry /= 10;
            (*length)++;
        }
    }
    // reverse
    for (i = 0; i < *length / 2; i++)
    {
        temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[*length - i - 1];
        str[*length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
    str[*length] = '\0';
}
int main()
{
    int n, k;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
    char str[100000];
    int length;
    pow(n, k, str, &length);
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the program, could you explain me why are there + '0' and - '0'? What do they do&

Comment: @glebchesnakov This algorithm computes your long number while STORING it to a string at the same time. How? I used ASCII codes. Let's say you've got a string composed of only 1 character and that character is `'0'`, in the computer, that character is actually stored as a number that's `48` (you can see the entire table here: https://www.asciitable.com/) Clear? Good! Now let's say you've got a digit that's `0 (0)`, and unlike `'0' (48)`, it got a value of 0 for real! How do you convert that letter to a char? Well, you add 48! (`+'0'`) and to convert it to a number again you subtract (`-'0'`).

Comment: @glebchesnakov So, the algorithm basically gets the last digit of a number (by dividing by 10 and getting the remainder `%`), then converts it to a char by adding `'0'`, then appends it to a string. But while it is looping, it also fetches all the digits which were stored again from the same string by subtracting `'0'`. Notice how this entire operation would give us a reversed result. This is why I reverse the result at the end. when converting a digit to a char, you add '0', and when converting a char to a digit, you subtract '0'. This would work with 123456789 because they're all in order.

Comment: У тебя в профиле Санкт Петербург, не обратил внимание, спасибо за разъяснение

Answer (score 1):

Your problem does not seem well specified.  You are not describing the problem or the limits in detail.

Regardless, here is some simple code to hopefully get you started.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;
    printf("Enter N:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    int k;
    printf("Enter K:\n");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    
    int result = pow(n,k);
    char text[100];
    sprintf(text, "%d", result);
    
    printf("The Answer is %s\n", text);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for any big numbers.

Comment: I have to print any number, for example: input n = 2, k = 82. Output in character massive-string: 4835703278458516698824704